# Comprimir byte[] de imagen

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

por favor su ayuda. Deseo comprimir los byte[] obtenidos desde una imagen en una webform para poder insertar en un campo de la base de datos tipo clob. Si la imagen tiene mas 4000 bytes no me permite insertar. Los bytes los estoy transformando a String64.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Bitmap bmp = ctlSignature.SaveSignature("");
byte[] imageData;

using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    stream.Position = 0;
    imageData = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
    stream.Close();
}

string strImagen = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
```

Comment: ¿Y si los comprimes en el frontend antes de pasarlos? Por cierto, convertir una imagen a Base64, hace que el tamaño se expanda en 2.5 a 3 veces más

Comment: @fredyfx Como los comprimo? Y en qué formato debería insertar en la base de datos? Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Información relacionada: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4715480/3613462

Comment: ¿Has investigado algo?

Comment: Si, pero yo solo quiero comprimir la imagen para poder insertar en la base. Porque clob y blob solo pemriten 4000. La imagen es una firma digital por lo que no tiene un tamaño fijo.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2006/04/tr-2006-45.pdf

Comment: Como puedo comprimir en el frontend? Lo que he encontrado es cambiar el tamaño de la imagen pero no aplica en este caso.

Comment: Es una buena pregunta, a investigar :D Toma, un atajo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14672943/3613462 Por otro lado, verifica la documentación que tengas sobre las firmas digitales